# Add subdirectories to Rails assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I am trying to integrate a Bootstrap framework into a Rails project. The framework comes with lots of html templates which I would like to use. Each template has several links to assets (css, images, js) which are all named something like:

```
href="assets/css/stylesheet.css"
```

By including the framework's files in the Rails `vendor/assets` folder I can access all these resources if I rename them all to

```
href="assets/stylesheet.css"
```

or using a Rails helper, but I don't want to have to do that for every single asset because I'd rather leave as much of the framework intact as possible for updates and such, and besides that would be super annoying to deal with.

Is there a way to have Rails access these files the way they are currently written?

(I know for example this is possible with Laravel Elixir).

Comment: what you want man?

Comment: search `@import "bootstrap-sprockets"; @import "bootstrap";` and `//= require bootstrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard procedure here is to add references to these in your `application.css` or equivalent file. There's usually a comment in that master file that looks like this:

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
*/
```

You can add other files to that manually, or just put your assets in there in a way that they get hoovered up properly by the asset pipeline.

Doing this means they all get packed down into the same distributable CSS file when you roll this out to production.

If you do want to compile this separately for whatever reason you need to alter `config/initializers/assets.rb` and add things like:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w[
  assets/stylesheet.css
]
```

That will force-compile another unrelated asset.